# How do i get the access token from the reques

Tags: c#, token, access-token, alexa-skills-kit

I'm using account linking on amazon and I've managed to configure it to send my user's acessToken by a Json. I looked in the amazon documentation and it says that I can find the token in `context.System.user.accessToken` but I can't find this path in my code, could you help me? I guess i need to make an interceptor to get this request and the token, but i have no idea how.

[JSON Input with acessToken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2E60.png)

[Token path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtgFB.png)

Comment: dear first deserialize the json into an object and access it from  ```session.user.accessToken```

Answer (score 0):

Within the handle function of your intentHandler, the argument `handlerInput` contains the access token. It is sent for each request:

```
const { accessToken } = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.user;
```

You can also have it within the user's session:

```
const { accessToken } = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.session.user;
```

> The accessToken field does not appear if null

More detail about Alexa requests in the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html)